# React componentDidUpdate Error

Tags: reactjs

Без componentDidUpdate счетчик работает, но решил попробовать сделать чтобы при обновлении страницы счетчик не сбрасывался на 0 и заюзал componentDidUpdate, вылетела ошибка - **×
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

```
    class Count extends React.Component {
state = {
    count: 0
}

countIncrease = () => {
    this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1
    })
};

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (prevProps.count !== this.state.count) {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count
        })
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <hr/>
            <p>Счетчик: {this.state.count}</p>
            <button onClick={this.countIncrease}>Счетчик+1</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Ну потому что компонент обновляется, когда его стейт обновляется. Т.е. каждый раз как вы обновите стейт с каунтом, то компонент перерисуется и снова обновит стейт и так далее..

Comment: Чтобы счетчик не сбрасывался при обновлении страницы сохраняйте значение где-то, в куках или просто в localStorage

Comment: @entithat понял, дело в том что в другом тренировочном проекте данные хранятся в redux store и в state для примера в тот же count значение прилетает из пропсов, в этом случае при юзании componentDidUpdate данные сохраняются, видимо там своя магия, думал сработает подобная штука и тут

Comment: ну это разные вещи